# Is mongodb 3.0 increasing their Key Index Limit?

Tags: mongodb

Our application uses a materialized path approach for storing trees.  We uses this approach because inserts are fast and allows us to query subtrees very easily.  In this approach we store the path to each node in the tree in a field on mongo called 'path'. We are facing an upcoming issue with mongo where our tree will no longer be able to be built into mongo because the path can not be longer than 1024 bytes b/c it is an index field.

Is mongo 3.0 increasing this arbitrary limit to something higher than 1024bytes?

Answer (score 2):

The [1024 byte limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) on index key length is still in place for MongoDB 3.0.

If the [materialized paths](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/) for your tree are approaching the key size limit, perhaps you should consider limiting the tree depth or description length for each node in the tree.

There are several alternative approaches to [modelling tree structures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) described in the MongoDB documentation, but there are obvious tradeoffs mentioned versus your current approach.

FYI, there is an open issue you can watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-3372: Allow indexing fields of arbitrary length](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3372).

Comment: Note: SERVER-3372 currently has a fixVersion of "3.1 Desired". That indicates it is a candidate issue to review during the 3.1 development cycle, but is not a guarantee the feature will be implemented. With the pluggable storage API added in MongoDB 3.0, I assume there will be considerations on how to map the exposed index key limit to any limits of the underlying storage engine (which may be greater or less than 1024 bytes).

Comment: I have reviewed the modeling tree structures document a great deal.  The only other viable option for a tree of this size is the nested set pattern which is  just a dog when it comes to inserts.  The materialized path is really the best option.  I also am using a shorter descriptor by using the npm shortid module vs the mongo object id.  I may have to migrate to TokuMX as their fields can have a 32k indexed field.

Comment: Has there been any movement on this issue? I am really in a tight spot. In our application there are millions of nodes in the tree and querying the tree and subtrees fast is critical. We also perform billions of db transactions on the tree and we have just found the materialized path approach to be the best mechanism for our needs. Is it possible to at least increase the allowed length? Even just doubling the allowed key length would help us immensely.

Comment: Stennie I just tried to use another plugin to do nested sets in mongo and even rewrote the plugin to use bulk operations to try to speed it up and rebuilding our tree took 30mins.. its really not an option for us.  Would love your input. Any way I can talk with someone at Mongo on how we should proceed?

Comment: @JakeDempsey For updates you're best watching the relevant issue in Jira: [SERVER-3372](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3372); as at August 2016 this issue is still in the backlog. There has been progress in terms of the pluggable storage engine API introduced in MongoDB 3.0 which enables storage engines that are not subject to the same limits as MMAP -- WiredTiger is now the default storage engine as at MongoDB 3.2. However, the key length limit remains at the integration layer (as at MongoDB 3.3) and there is no obvious workaround short of changing your data model.